# why is video volume low using MPMoviePlayerController on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

My app uses MPMoviePlayerController to record videos and play them back.  It works fine on iPad, but the volume is very low on iPhone.  I tried setting up a AVAudioSession as well and setting the path to speaker, but that doesn't seem to help.  How can I fix this?  I am running iOS 7 devices